# Why does rustc not run my simple "hello world" program?

Tags: rust

I just set up Rust according to the doc and created my first program.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I saved it as `main.rs` and kicked off using:

```
[root@localhost hello_world] rustc main.rs
[root@localhost hello_world]
```

But no output ever appears. Running `rustc --version` does show the version number, so considering the install went without problem, I am wondering where the problem is.

Comment: rustc is the compiler. It should have created an output file. Maybe `a.out` or something. You need to run that.

Comment: Seems to preferred way to build and run things now is the `Cargo` tool. Check out the tutorial: http://doc.rust-lang.org/intro.html

Comment: Well, I have only `main main.rs` @Thilo

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. You saved me lots of days :) I do get extra 2 lines of output though as you can see [in this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qvEx.gif) should I be worried?

Answer (score 12):

Rust is a compiled language. `rustc` is the compiler, which takes a source file and produces a binary which can then be executed; it does not itself execute the code, however. You must take the binary it produces (by default, the source filename minus the `.rs` extension) and execute it yourself with `./main` or similar.

If you use Cargo, there is `cargo run` which compiles the code if necessary and then runs it.